# Manifest.json not copied to dist

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

My Angular project's purpose is to achieve "add to homescreen" mobile functionality. In that process I choose manifest/PWA methodology and I have created manifest.json in the root folder of project on the same level of index.html(root template), and added the manifest.json in the head section of root template (index.html) with following statement: .
But upon "ng build" I see the manifest file not copied to the dist and as a result it's displays the following errors on clicking "add to homescreen" in "dev tools->application->manifest"

Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. looking out for help!

```
**localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:4200/src/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.**
```

**below is manifest file:**

```
{
  "short_name": "Bus Express",
  "name": "BusEx",
  "start_url": "/",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "theme_color": "#fff",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/rateexpress128.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/rateexpress144.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "144x144"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: have you added manually?

Comment: Yes Pradeep. Added manually. When click the manifest file link from "dev tools/application/manifest" it contains following:



`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /src/manifest.json</pre>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 8):

Files are not copied by default to the dist folder. You need to add them manually in the angular.json config file (if Angular version >= 6) in the `assets` option, [see here for an example](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes/blob/master/angular.json#L19) or in the `.angular-cli.json` config file (if Angular version < 6), [see here for an example](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes/blob/original/.angular-cli.json#L10).

Comment: Thank you so much Guillaume. Now it got fixed after adding manifest.json as below in the Angular.json file. "assets": [ "src/favicon.ico", "src/assets", "src/manifest.json"], But I have tried this change in a sample project of angular 5, and my actual project is angular1.5 and it doesn't contain either angular-cli.json or the angular.json files, so where do i add this change in my angular 1.5 project? and how can i retain <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"> in index.html file which is currently removed after gulp build. We use gulp build.

Answer (score 2):

`go to angular.json`

`add manifest.json location in assets`

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
          ],
```

restart dev server using
`ng serve`

Answer (score 1):

Also, I have changed the name of the file to `manifest.json` internally, while `angular.json` contained the entry `manifest.webmanifest`...